# How do I dynamically add &autoplay=1 to youtube embed codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, youtube, autoplay

This is an examples of the youtube embed code on my site:

```
<object width="525" height="320"><param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/yciTqWafKPU?version=3">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/yciTqWafKPU?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="525" height="320" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque">
</object>
```

I believe I need to add `&autoplay=1` to this: `<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/yciTqWafKPU?version=3&autoplay=1">` and this: `<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/yciTqWafKPU?version=3&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="525" height="320" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque">`

I need to do this dynamically with JQuery. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without too much difficulty, I would have thought...

```
$('param[name="movie"]').val(function(i, oldVal) {
    return oldVal + (oldVal.indexOf('?') ? '&autoplay=1' : '?autoplay=1');
});
$('embed').prop('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
    return oldSrc + (oldSrc.indexOf('?') ? '&autoplay=1' : '?autoplay=1');
}
```

You might prefer to do a slightly more specific selector, for instance `$('embed[src^="http://www.youtube.com/"]')` or perhaps `$('object param[name="movie"]')` -- it depends on what your page contains elsewhere...

See the API reference:

- [`attribute-equals` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector)
- [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val)
- [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop'`

Comment: @Justin You're using a version of jQuery before 1.6. In the current version, `prop` is introduced, but you want `attr` for previous versions.

Comment: so for some reason the first time the code is executed, the video doesn't play automatically. It works the second time the code is run and so on. What does this have to do with?

Comment: @lonesomeday - +1 - This answer helped me solve my issue on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423973/dynamically-add-parameters-to-an-embedded-url/

Comment: @JustinMeltzer - I had a similar question and I am not using `autoplay=1` but I tried it seeing your comment and it worked fine for me using the same code as above.

Answer (score 0):

To play a YouTube movie by JavaScript, you'll better use the JavaScript Player API:

http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

(Yes I know this is not precisely the answer to the OP's question).

Answer (score 0):

How to auto-play youtube link?

1) Use the code and simply change the url to http://www.youtube.com/v/?version=3&autoplay=1

```
<object width="525" height="320"><param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/yciTqWafKPU?version=3">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/yciTqWafKPU?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="525" height="320" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque">
</object>
```

2) remove the &autoplay=0 to click and play manually!