# Dynamically Add Parameters to an Embedded URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, dynamic-data

I use the program [jAlbum](http://jalbum.net/) with skin [Lightflow](http://kaya.jalbum.net/LightFlow/v3/index.html) to build a gallery. I am embedding YouTube videos inside the gallery. The program produces the following HTML  (for an individual embedded video) look like this:

```
<div class="item">
 <img class="content hidden" src="thumbs/video.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="ref hidden">item27</div>
    <div class="caption"><h3></h3></div>
    <div class="comment hidden"></div>
    <div class="author hidden"></div>
    <div class="params hidden">lightwindow_width=640,lightwindow_height=360</div>
    <div class="info hidden"></div>
    <div class="embed hidden"><iframe width="640" height="360" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/E-lTPK5sQAA?fs=1&feature=oembed" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <div class="thumbWidth hidden">350</div>
    <div class="thumbHeight hidden">231</div>
    <a id="item27" class="lightwindow hidden" title="" rel="gal[cat]" 
href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-lTPK5sQAA" ></a>
    </div>
```

I would like to add some parameters to the youtube embed code. The parameters are `rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3`

I cannot add these inside the gallery (or at least I am ignorant of how) so I need to add these dynamically to the end of the YouTube `src` code after the page is loaded in the browser.

How do I go about doing this? Please provide examples as Javascript can throw me for a loop.

***EDIT 1***

I have attempted this code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('iframe').attr('src', $j(this).attr('src') + 
  '&rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3'));
```

and when I syntax errors are thrown in dreamweaver and Firebug says I am `missing ; before statement` What am I missing in the code?

***EDIT 2***

When I try the above code the `src` is changed to `undefined&rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3`

Comment: Don't you have an extra closing parantheses there?

Comment: @inhan - You were correct. Any ideas on my other issue now? Thanks!

Comment: What does `console.log($j('iframe').attr('src') + '\n' + $j(this).attr('src'));` output?

Comment: @inhane - This is what is shows `http://www.youtube.com/embed/E-lTPK5sQAA?fs=1&feature=oembed&rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3 undefined` However I was able to find a solution. My solution is posted below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this figured out after I saw [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144926/how-do-i-dynamically-add-autoplay-1-to-youtube-embed-codes). Here is the solution:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('iframe').prop('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
return oldSrc + (oldSrc.indexOf('?') ? 
'&rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3' : 
'?rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3');
})
```

Note: You must be using jQuery 1.6+ for prop to work.

Answer (score 0):

To append options you can do this:

```
$('iframe').each(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src + '&showinfo=1&autohide=1');
});
```

To replace options in bulk in a piece of html you can do this assuming that all urls to be replaced have this format `http://www.youtube.com/embed/id?params`:

```
var addYTparams = function(html, params){
    return html.replace(/(youtube.com.+\?).+/, '$1'+params);
};
addYTparams($el.html(), 'rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3');
```

Comment: you mean + '&rel=0&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3', right?

Comment: yeah, whatever options he wants to put.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I am attempting the first one mentioned and I get errors. My question is edited to show the code. Why is this error happening?

Comment: Fixed that error (see above) now I lose my `src` when trying the first code. Ideas?